# Make Visual Studio Code run in the virtual environment of a remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-debugging, remote-server, virtual-environment

I have connect the VSCode to the remote server by instruction provided online: [Remote development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). My code contains tensor flow, where I installed it in the virtual environment I created in the server. Is it possible for me to run the code in the interactive window successfully? So far, when I ran the code, the interactive window gave me the error "module tensor flow not found". I have to run it in the terminal window, but by running it in the terminal, I am unable to check the temp variables which help me debug.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by [changing the kernel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) to the my virtual environment.